# Divide two difftime objects

Tags: r, datetime

I have three time (`POSIXct`) objects `t1`, `t2`, `t3` which specify the time duration to complete a task.

I found `t1`, `t2`, `t3` by doing the following:

```
t1 <- as.POSIXct("2016-10-30 13:53:34") - as.POSIXct("2016-10-30 13:35:34")
t2 <- as.POSIXct("2016-10-30 14:53:34") - as.POSIXct("2016-10-30 14:35:34")
t3 <- as.POSIXct("2016-10-30 15:50:34") - as.POSIXct("2016-10-30 15:40:34")
```

I want to find the ratios `t1/t3` and `t2/t3`. However, I get the following error:

```
t1/t3
# Error in `/.difftime`(t1, t3) : 
#   second argument of / cannot be a "difftime" object
```

I understood that two `difftime` objects cannot be divided. Is there any way that I could find the result of dividing two `difftime` objects?

Comment: Do you want to divide by the number of seconds in the interval?  Number of hours?  Number of days?  Also, give code that actually duplicates your `t1`, `t2` and `t3`.

Comment: I would like to divide it by number of seconds.

Comment: You can convert a `difftime` object `d` to seconds with `as.numeric(d, units='secs')`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To divide by a `difftime` you must convert it to numeric.  If, as you stated in a comment, you would like the answer to be expressed in seconds, you can specify the `'secs'` units. For example:

```
t1/as.double(t3, units='secs')
```

As @JonathanLisic notes, `as.double` does not generally take a `units` parameter, and this won't work for generic time classes.  It is the `S3` method for `difftime` which takes the parameter.

Comment: It's important to note that this conversion is not necessarily relevant to other DateTimeClasses.  e.g. `a1 <- strptime("2016-10-30 13:53:34", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"); as.double(a1,units="days")` still returns seconds from epoch.

Comment: @JonathanLisic True, thank you for the addition.  The reason it works here is that `as.double` is an `S3` method for `difftime`.

Comment: I'm quite surprised that `as.double` is S3 generic, but `as.numeric` is _not_! First case I've seen in R of actually requiring `as.double`...

Answer (score 4):

As of today's date (9/2018), you can use `as.numeric()` to turn your `difftime` values into numeric values. ie, if you were to take

```
as.numeric(t3)
```

R will return 10 as desired.

Answer (score 3):

@MatthewLundberg's answer is more correct, but I'll suggest an alternative just to help illustrate the underlying structures of time-based objects in R are always just numbers:

```
unclass(t1)/unclass(t3)
# [1] 1.8
# attr(,"units")
# [1] "mins"
```

Note that, in terms of units, the approach of `t1/as.double(t3, units = 'secs')` doesn't make much sense, since the units of the output are min/sec, whereas this answer is unit-free.

Note further that this approach is a bit dangerous, since by default, `-.POSIXt` (which is ultimately called when you define `t1`, `t2`, and `t3`) *automatically* chooses the units of the output (at core, `-.POSIXt` here will call `difftime` with the default `units = "auto"`). In this case, we are (maybe) lucky that all 3 are given units, but consider `t4`:

```
t4 = as.POSIXct('2017-10-21 12:00:35') - as.POSIXct('2017-10-21 12:00:00')
t4
# Time difference of 35 secs
```

Again, if we use `t4` in a ratio, we'll probably get the wrong units.

We can avoid this by explicitly calling `difftime` and declaring the units upfront:

```
t1 = difftime("2016-10-30 13:53:34", "2016-10-30 13:35:34", units = 'mins')
t2 = difftime("2016-10-30 14:53:34", "2016-10-30 14:35:34", units = 'mins')
t3 = difftime("2016-10-30 15:50:34", "2016-10-30 15:40:34", units = 'mins')
t4 = difftime('2017-10-21 12:00:35', '2017-10-21 12:00:00', units = 'mins')
t4
# Time difference of 0.5833333 mins
```

Comment: Any idea why we cannot take a ratio of ``difftime`` objects (and get unit-free number)? Is it an oversight in the implementation of ``\`` or there is some fundamental difficulty?

Comment: @PatrickT it's a good question but I don't know the answer. seems like an oversight to me